# Better place to put common functions?

Tags: python, module, package

I'm working on building a custom package for functions I commonly use, and it has several functions that do not fit in any specific module and are used by several modules. I've been putting them in `__init__.py`, and it works, but I've seen many tutorials that recommend a very small `__init__.py`. Is there any better place I can put them?

I want to be able to call them like this:

```
import mypackage

#functions in modules
mypackage.module.function()

#common functions
mypackage.function()
```

Where do I put these functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a 'utilities' package/file for storing re-usable pieces of code and then import them into your files which could benefit from them !

And as for your init.py file - I'd leave that empty !

```
# utilities.py
def method():
    return None

# Some class
from utilities import *

nothing_burger = method()
print nothing_burger
```

If you add the parent folder to the python path, within the command_line_interface.py or data_access.py file you can import

`from extras.utilities import *`

and you will have access to all your re-usable methods

```
. Parent
    |
    ├── cli
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── command_line_interface.py
    ├── persistence
    │   ├── data_access.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── extras
        ├── exceptions.py
        ├── utilities.py
        └── __init__.py
```